HTML Report is not being generated with multiple-cucumber-html-reporter for Cypress Automations
I was trying to setup reports with Mochawesome but I could not get it to work like I wanted, so then I tried these steps to use cucumber-html-reporter instead: Can I generate cucumbur html report in cypress?
At first it worked perfectly, but as I continue working on my automations and other settings, I realized the report stopped being generated.
Trying to trace my steps, here is what I remember I did before it stopped working:

Delete everything I added related to Mochawesome.
I changed the value for "name" in both package.json and package-lock.json. I did this because my root folder was called cypress-course and renamed it to cypress-demo. Then while I was adding some settings to the package.json I noticed it still showed the old name, and I updated it.

This is the current version: https://github.com/gagm96/cypress-demo
And this is what I've tried:

Undo the change to the "name" valus in both package.json and package-lock.json
Reinstall cucumber-html-reporter and follow the steps from scratch.
Then I tried using multiple-cucumber-html-reporter instead.
Reinstall mochawesome reporter again.
Drop all changes and go back to before a started configuring the reports.
Follow these steps again: Can I generate cucumbur html report in cypress?

I still cannot get the report.

You have used an out of date version of Cucumber, this is the version you should be using:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor.
If you take a minute to read the docs, you can see

ℹ️ The repository has recently moved from github.com/TheBrainFamily to github.com/badeball. Read more about the transfer of ownership here.

which links to

Transfer of ownership
Due to personal reasons, the previous maintainers of this package are stepping down and handing the reigns over to me, a long-time contributor to the project and a user of it myself. This is a responsibility I'm very excited about. Furthermore, I'd like to thank @lgandecki ++ for all the work that they've done so far.


I was struggling with this recently and this project helped me:
https://github.com/burakkaygusuz/cypress-cucumber-html-report-example/tree/master
Give it a try. For what I've seen in your project, you still need to add a js file for the report config. And maybe you will need to adjust a bit your scripts in package.json so it can work and also the cypress.config file.
I hope this helps.
